# VS2010 linq Goes To shortcut

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I am trying to make a shortcut for the linq "goes To" => string. Does anyone know how to do this?

I would like to hit ctrl+= and get =>

Comment: Why, out of interest? It's only two characters...

Comment: @Jon: I use it a lot. I know it really isn't the end of the world, but now that I have thought about it there has to be a way to do it:)

Comment: But what shortcut would you bind that's quicker than `=>` anyway? I'm really struggling to see how this is going to help your productivity...

Comment: @Jon: I use item for parameter name in lambda expressions usually. A shortcut is better than writing 'item => item.'  Also Intellisense offers crazy things till you write =>

Comment: @Jon: Ufuk has answered for me:)

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: That may make a bit more sense, with the parameter name as well - but personally I tend to tailor the parameter name to the situation anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ReSharper, you can use [live templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/codeTemplate.html)

Comment: I'd guess you could use plain VS Code snippets if you don't have ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that, without creating your own compiler and redefining the grammar. C# doesn't allow C-style `#DEFINE` (if that was what you where thinking about).

I also doubt the practicality of such a solution. You would need to use a single char (in order for it to be a shortcut, since making it longer kind of defeats the purpose), which is not a valid variable name, and is not yet defined as an operator. I can't think of anything that would be easier to type than the two chars `=>`.

By any chance, do you use a non-english keyboard layout ? Many european keyboard layouts, including that of my own language, requires shift or other modifiers to type many of the C# operators. You could consider switching to UK keyboard layout for coding - it's easy to shift once you are back in email (or whatever), and it saves you some keystrokes.